# Rename SAS variables in merge

Tags: join, merge, sas

Suppose I have the following dataset *lookup:*

```
ID   T001  T002  T002  T004  T005
1    0     1     2     3     4
2    1     2     3     4     5
```

And I want to merge this onto my main dataset *main:*

```
proc sql;
create table main as
select a.*, b.*
from main as a
left join lookup as b on a.ID = b.ID;
quit;
```

However, this will merge the variables at "T001", "T002", "T003" etc.
I am trying to rename the variables with the merge/join, without having to manually rename each of them as there are 100's of these variables in the dataset. I am looking to get something like

```
ID   V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
1    0     1     2     3     4
2    1     2     3     4     5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the variables names dynamically with a simple macro function after the join

```
data have;
input ID T001 T002 T003 T004 T005;
datalines;
1 0 1 2 3 4
2 1 2 3 4 5
;

%macro rn;
   %do i = 1 %to 5;
      T00&i. = V&i.
   %end;
%mend;

proc datasets lib=work nolist;
   modify have;
   rename %rn;
run;quit;
```

EDIT:

```
data have;
   array t T001-T586 (586*100);
run;

%macro rn;
   %do i=1 %to 586;
      T%sysfunc(putn(&i., z3.)) = V&i.
   %end;
%mend;

proc datasets lib=work nolist;
   modify have;
   rename %rn;
run;quit;
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I have 100's of these variables, though, where for example it ends at T586, how will I adapt the above, as I suppose "T00&i." won't work, given the leading zeros?

Comment: Just edited the code above. See if that works for you :-)